# Api to Generate Reports in mylyn, Tasktop Pro

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mylyn, tasktop

I have been an active user for tasktop Pro. I admire its simplicity and robustness. I am specially impressed with the time tracking options it provides.

I was feeling a need to use command line / batch / shell script / maven / ant or any other automator tools which allows me to create reports without the need to visit the 'Create Personal report' in Tasktop Pro. Is there any form of API available to access those resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no API available for accessing time tracking data. You could consider opening a request for this feature at https://tasktop.com/bugs